Parsing data with a varying structure from XML to a List<string>
I have a XML data representing a single client loaded into a web browser such as this:
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?-->
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <document>
        <Name>Carl</Name>
        <Surname>Smith</Surename>
        <Age>40</Age>
        <Gender>M</Gender>
    </document>
</body>

and the resulting web page displays data in this manner:
Carl Smith 40 M
Said web page truly shows just a simple string of information and nothing else.
There are several issues with this.

There are 10 - 15 templates for the XML data structure. For example one template may be missing age, the other will start with surnmane and the third will have additional information. Meaning that there is no standardization whatsoever.

Each client has depending on a template 68 - 278 (exactly) attributes/elements in their respective XML. So the above example is truly just as bare as it gets to get the point across.


How to parse this XML into a List<string>? I would like this List to have one piece of information from the XML as one item in this list. To carry on with the example from above the result would look like this:
List[0] = "Carl"
List[1] = "Smith"
List[2] = "40" (yup, even numbers will be converted to string)
List[3] = "M"
and so on..
I suppose the answer would be something akin to How do I extract these XML elements into a List<string>? but since my elements (attributes) have a different naming each time I am somewhat lost.
I suspect the code look something like this (taken from another post) but I do not know what to put in a place of YXYXYXXYX since the element/attribute changes for each row:
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {

     string _url = _UrlMaker.GetUrl(); //method which extracts URL with the XML data
     WebClient client = new WebClient(); 
     var xml = client.DownloadString(_url); //this should load the XML?

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        var list = doc.Root.Elements(YXYXYXXYX)
                           .Select(element => element.Value)
                           .ToList();                
    }
}

Could anyone provide me with code for this issue?

You can fetch all values to a list via :
List<string> values = doc.Descendants("document")
                                 .Elements()
                                 .Select(element => element.Value)
                                 .ToList();

Refer the below code for more reference:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string xmlData = @"<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <document>
        <Name>Carl</Name>
        <Surname>Smith</Surname>
        <Age>40</Age>
        <Gender>M</Gender>
    </document>
</body>
</html>";

        
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlData); // load the string as XDocument

        
        List<string> values = doc.Descendants("document")
                                 .Elements()
                                 .Select(element => element.Value)
                                 .ToList(); // get values to a string list

        
        values.ForEach(Console.WriteLine); // Print each value
    }
}


Refer the attached .netFiddle here


Hello! Thank you, upon calling my method I have gotten this error:
System.Xml.XmlException: 'Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no whitespace characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 2, position 3.'
Any idea?

now I see why, the first line of the XML im parsing from is like this:
'' but it should start with '<?xml'. I might be asking a lot here but is there a simple way to change this in my own code please?

This could be a possible solution:
var url = "your URL";
using var httpClient = new HttpClient()
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
 
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var htmlContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var doc = XDocument.Parse(htmlContent);

var list = doc.Root
       .DescendantsAndSelf()
       .Where(e => !e.HasElements && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value))
       .Select(e => e.Value.ToString())
       .ToList();


phenomenal, thank you! Just like mr. Nanayakkara's case this seems to be the way. I just have to resolve the subsequent error and I can close this issue.

silly question, but is my document even an XML? I was told it should be.. but since the first line (now edited) seems illegal..

No, its actually a HTML. This also has opening and closing tags, but strictly speaking, its not a XML.

thank you! So can I somehow change it to XML or should I choose a different parsing method?

I´ve edited my answer again. This should be working also with this HTML (when you have all the closing tags)

thank you, the problem is that my HTML (formaly thought to be XML) output changes so I cannot just put it into a string like in you answer. Is there a way to download the html code ?

I´ve changed my post again. This should work with any URL (when the HTML is valid and has no comments etc.)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

thank you, is it possible to have it be done synchroniously?

Hmm....you should do it asynchronusly. Its possible but not recommended.

I have managed to solve it like this:
I have loaded the html to a string, turned it into a list and deleted 1st tw rows and turned back into a string and then properly parsed it according to your previous instructions not using the asynchronous path.
thank you so much for your time!
